# Iterating over numpy array except the same element

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array and I want to iterate over it two times. The idea is to perform an operation on each pair of combination of the array except itself, like:

[image]

Where B is numpy array of 36 array of 4 elements like

```
  [[  9.106593 279.82645  192.9962   381.61804 ]
   [  9.106593 279.82645  192.9962   381.61804 ]]
```

and L is elements of 36 array elements like:

```
  [1,2,.......,35]
```

Can someone please help me in finding bit elegant numpy solution using broadcasting? Thanks

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Comment: Output-wise the code snippet is correct but I don't want to have loops; need to have a broadcasting solution

Comment: FYI, your code example won't operate on every pair since you use range(len(a)) which gives [0, 1, 2] but your array is not 3x3, it's 3x4.  I recommend you instead use `height, width = a.shape` then height will be 3 and width will be 4.

Comment: Is it intentional that you multiply rows of `a` instead of elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think your fastest way to do this is to perform the operation on all pairs, then only print the results you are interested in.  I'm assuming that the operation is as simple as the multiply example you have given.

I'll give an example using meshgrid for a 1d array, and leave it to you to extend to 2d.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]
print(a)
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4])

x, y = np.meshgrid(a, a)
print(x)
>>> array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
           [1, 2, 3, 4],
           [1, 2, 3, 4],
           [1, 2, 3, 4]])
print(y)
>>> array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
           [2, 2, 2, 2],
           [3, 3, 3, 3],
           [4, 4, 4, 4]])

z = x*y
print(z)
>>> array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
           [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
           [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
           [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])
```

Now the results you wanted to ignore are on the diagonal and you can print each element, omitting them like this.

```
height, width = z.shape
for h in range(height):
    for w in range(width):
        if h == w:
            continue  # Skips this one.
        print(z[h][z])
```

I'm not sure why you want to do it twice, so it may be you just need two print statements, or more complex.  If you can comment on that I can suggest something.

EDIT:
I see you've added a comment that you don't want for loops at all.  You can just print the whole thing with `print(z)` and ignore the values you're not interested in, or if you're passing the values to something else you can ignore them at that stage.

Comment: The idea is to compute distance between all elements except itself and that distance would be used in cost function; as the arrays are quite big so I am not sure if meshgrid solution is practical, thanks anyways for the help

Comment: @Mahdi Okay, so your equation is then `np.sqrt(a[i]**2 + a[j]**2)`  You can then do `a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) ** 2` to square it straight away then do meshgrid and the result will be that you only need to square once per element rather than every time you use the value.  Then `x` and `y` will already be squared and you can calculate `z = np.sqrt(x + y)`  Why is it that you don't think meshgrid is not practical?  Are you worried about the overhead of computing the diagonals that are unused?  Can you tell me how big the arrays will be?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help, I have edited the question; hopefully it makes  more sense now